# Group by main words

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, collections, set

Consider the following TreeSet:

- **blue** flower
- **blue** big car
- **blue** hat 123
- **red** apple 123
- **red** car
- **red** shirt
- **red** jacket
- some words (must be ignored)
- useless words (must be ignored)

This set has 2 main words **blue** and **red** along with different key words.
I need to group by those main words so that I get a list with all possible key words. Something like:

- **blue**: flower, big, car, hat, 123
- **red**: apple, 123, car, shirt, jacket

I think the steps should be as follows:

1. Detect main word

   - the list is in alphabetical order, so the main words occur next to each other
   - it can only be the first word in an entry
   - it consists of at least 3 letters
   - not every entry has a main word (entries *some words* and *useless words* should be just skipped)
2. Group by main word

   - some kind of "merging": take all entries with the same main word and remove it from every entry, so that only the remaining key words are left
     - <del>blue</del> flower
     - <del>blue</del> big car
     - <del>blue</del> hat 123
   - in this case the key words: *flower, big, car, hat, 123* are left

Could somebody please give me a suggestion how to accomplish it and what I need for that?

Comment: It's not clear which the main words are

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner They need to be found programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need regex. Split each string on whitespace using `String.split(" ")`, and then examine the first item to compare it your list of "main" words.

```
TreeSet<String> originalSet = // as per question
List<String> mainWords = Arrays.asList("blue", "red");
Map<String, Set<String>> words = new HashMap<>();
for(String mainWord : mainWords) {
    words.put(mainWord, new HashSet<String>());
}
for(String line : originalSet) {
    String[] items = line.split(" ");
    if(words.keySet().contains(items[0])) {
        for(int i = 1 ; i < items.length ; i++) {
            words.get(items[0]).add(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just read the comment that the main words "need to be found programatically". My solution is based on the assumption that you already know what the main words are.